# Angular Material2 with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, angular-material2

I would like to use angular-material2 with IE, but I am unable to display any components on IE. Is there any documentation or guidelines I could refer?

Comment: If you use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) you have to edit the polyfills.ts file ([see issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4822#issuecomment-280888862)).

Comment: Also what version of IE are you targeting?